# How do I get the best reproduction when playing a digital video on a PAL CRT monitor?

Tags: analog, monitors, pal

I have a digital video that I need to show on a CRT monitor (PAL). It will play from a digital player and be fed to the monitor via s-video or composite video.

**What should I think of to get the highest possible playback quality on the monitor?**

I guess that it would be best to transcode the video an interlaced PAL video file in the right resolution so that the transcoding won't be done sloppily by the digital player?

Answer (score 3):

Yes - if the monitor is Standard Definition PAL, then you should make sure the source video is 25fps 720x576 with interlaced fields at 50i, [lower field first](https://www.provideocoalition.com/field_order/).

S-video should give a better image than composite, as the luminance signal is sent separately from the colour signal (which is combined into a single signal, reducing the original quality).  Component should give a better signal than s-video as the red, green, and blue signals are all sent separately.